# Need help with a sub-standard RS232

Tags: uart, rs232, ttl, converter

I've built a UART-RS232 converter based on max232 and it works well... but not for what I need :)

According to [Maxim's datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX220-MAX249.pdf) the RS232 side signal voltage should be theoretically +/-10v (5v * 2), but in practice it is +/-8v.

This isn't a problem when you use the interface on standard RS232 ports but in my case it simply doesn't work and investigating on the PCB of my device of interest, that exposes a DB9 connector, I've found it isn't a real standard RS232 port but the RX and TX pins are connected, through 2 transistors, to a microprocessor UART interface.

This kind of port works well with the PC RS232 that uses a +/-12v voltage levels so I suspect the max232 output is simply too low for it.

Is there a way to boost up the max232 +/-8v output to +/-12v??
If it's useful I can take 12v from the device.

Edit: What about "combine" two identical RS232 signal (max232 has two converter but I'm actually using only one of them) forming a new signal equal to twice voltage level? Is it possible?

**Edit2 - 2013/05/22:**
The signal voltage levels don't seem to be the problem just because that device works using a USB-RS232 adapter and in this case the signal levels are about +/-6.5v (at least on my converter).

I drew the interface circuit from the device pcb to better understand what's happening :)
[image: device schematic]

Notice: I don't know if that diode is a zener or not

Then I made some new tests using my breadboard sniffing data directly from the cable.

I found that **the RS232-RX part works as expected**: if I "stimulate" the device sending data on the RS232-TX not from the max232 but from the PC serial port the device replies as expected on the RS232-RX line and the max232 translates the received signals as expected.

So at this point I need to know in which max232 output line and my PC serial port output line are different. What should I try in your opinion??

**Edit3 23/05/2013:**
Just to better explain what I'm speaking about...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWxT64.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think it's worth investigating why it's not meeting the datasheet specification - it may be a simple fix.

Comment: Actually with a 3K load +/- 7.3v is in spec from what I can see for a MAX232. I can't think of an easy solution, you could use a DS1488 like a PC uses but then you'll need your own +/- 12V supply.

Comment: @pjc50 8v is actually in spec and accordingly with the datasheet "The typical driver output voltage swing is ±8V when loaded with a nominal 5kΩ RS-232 receiver and VCC = +5V.". The 10v is theoretical just because it comes from a voltage doubler.

Comment: @PeterJ I think I'll explore your solution... if I could recycle a ds1488 from an old mobo it should be a great solution. The 12v isn't a problem in my case.

Comment: A two-variable problem here. If communications to/from a PC work (presumably via a terminal program), communications to/from a UART via a MAX232 don't work, and the voltage levels out of the MAX232 are in spec, the problem seems to be with the UART and not the hardware - i.e. the protocol / speed / data, not the signal levels. You could always convert the PC serial port data to UART with another MAX232, then back to RS232 to really understand if voltage plays a role.

Comment: If you are confident that under-voltage (compared to expected, regardless of the spec) is the problem, temporarily paralleling another resistor with the one in the receiver to reduce the effective resistance could be a way to test it.  Normally using a resistor as an RS232 level converter would leave you short an inverter, but if the device works with a computer RS232 port the inversion sense must be right.

Comment: If the device simply exposes the microprocessor UART pins, then you either do not need a UART->RS232 converter to communicate with it (go microprocessor to microprocessor, with whatever level shifter necessary in between, if any) or else use two UART->RS232 converters (basically give the board a proper RS232 front end, which mates with the proper RS232 interface you have built on your side.)

Comment: The Common faults with RS232 connections are Settings of the UARTs. (Windows Terminal did not like the settings changed while "Connected") and bad physical connections (Very thin/poor quality or damaged wire or connectors). When you've been called to the factory floor for yet another "Issue" that required binning the serial lead you start paying attention and cash for good leads. I hate RS232 over ethernet cable!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. "in which max232 output line and my PC serial port output line are different" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Madmanguruman please take a look at the latest image. I suppose there is something different between what's outputted by my PC serial port and what comes from the MAX232 just because the first works but not the latter :)

If I sniff the data sent it's the same for both PC port and max232.

Comment: @Madmanguruman UART logic levels are "inverted" compared with the RS232 ones, afaik it can't work.

The transmitted data appears the same if I sniff it with a PC serial port that implement a in-spec RS-232. With "different" I mean something like the "load" on that line for example.

Comment: I finally found the problem :) The device of interest pretends the use of the parity bit... but in my case I think

Comment: ... the wireless module attached to the PC probably consumes the parity bit. Is there a way in your opition to "re-generate" the parity bit on the max232 just before to transmit data to the final device of interest?

Comment: @mrfree, the parity generation happens in the micro or whatever is driving the MAX232. BTW if you've solved the original problem you can answer it yourself so it doesn't hang around unanswered and it might help someone in the future, especially if you don't mind adding what you're interfacing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was an undocumented even parity bit required by the device I need to control (a Bentel Kyo300 alarm security panel), but even if I found which the problem was a limitation in the serial wireless modules prevents to re-generate the parity bit on the destination end-point.

Those serial-wireless adapters have, in fact, fixed serial-side configuration of 8N1... I solved buying better and configurable serial wireless modules (APC220) :)

I've learned a lot about hardware-level serial communication during this discussion so I'm happy even if I spent few more euros ;)

Comment: Now that you posted your own answer, don't forget to accept it! Otherwise the question will remain open in the software and get periodically bumped up and affect statistics.